# Ignored endhead/endfoot when using longtable with caption-package

Tags: captions, longtable, page-breaking

If I use `longtable` and the `caption`-package it sometimes happens, that `\endhead` and `\endfoot` are ignored if the table breaks. If I don't load the `caption`-package it works as intended. Does someone know what is causing this problem and how to prevent it?

Edit: I tried to use an older version of `longtable` (2020/01/07 v4.13) and there it still worked. I compared both .sty-files and the problem occurs due to the exclusion of the following code in the definition of `\def\LT@output{...}`:

```
\global\@colroom\@colht
\global\vsize\@colht
\vbox
   {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
```

whereas in the new version of longtable only:

```
\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi
```

is used. But I don't know what this code is used for and why it only occurs in combination with the `caption`-package and if it is a feature or a bug.

Here is a MWE to show the problem:

```tex
\documentclass[a6paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption} % commenting this line shows the desired output

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{l}
         \hline
        \textbf{Header}\\
        \hline
        \endhead
        \hline
        \caption{some caption}
        \endfoot
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
        test \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: output with ignored endhead endfoot]

Comment: There's a layout problem with your table: the  `\caption{…}` command should be in the `\endfirsthead` section.

Comment: @Bernard I know in this MWE the caption seems to be in the wrong place, but in my application I would like to use a modified caption there and it has been working fine until I updated all packages today and some update must have broken it.